# Is it possible to dump from Timescale without hypertable insertions?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, timescaledb

I followed the manual on: https://docs.timescale.com/v1.0/using-timescaledb/backup

When I dump it into a binary file everything work out as expected (can restore it easily).

However, when I dump it into plain text SQL, insertions to hyper tables will be created. Is that possible to create INSERTION to the table itself?

Say I have an 'Auto' table with columns of id,brand,speed 
and with only one row: 1,Opel,170

dumping into SQL will result like this:

```
INSERT INTO _timescaledb_catalog.hypertable VALUES ...
INSERT INTO _timescaledb_internal._hyper_382_8930_chunk VALUES (1, 'Opel',170);
```

What I need is this (and let TS do the work in the background):

```
INSERT INTO Auto VALUES (1,'Opel',170);
```

Is that possible somehow? (I know I can exclude tables from pg_dump but that wouldn't create the needed insertion)

Comment: I don't know TimescaleDB, but you could try to exclude that schema when dumping: `pg_dump --exclude-schema=_timescaledb_internal ...` of course this only makes sense if `auto` actually exists as a regular table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Yes it will exclude all the timescale insertion but wont replace it with the regular one.(Auto exists as regular table)

Answer (score 1):

Beatrice. Unfortunately, `pg_dump` will dump commands that mirror the underlying implementation of Timescale. For example, `_hyper_382_8930_chunk` is a chunk underlying the `auto` hypertable that you have.

Might I ask why you don't want `pg_dump` to behave this way? The SQL file that Postgres creates on a dump is intended to be used by `pg_restore`. So as long as you dump and restore and see correct state, there is no problem with dump/restore.

Perhaps you are asking a different question?

Answer (score -1):

you can use the child_process module in Node.js to run shell commands. Here's a simple script that runs the pg_dump command:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const user = 'user';
const host = 'host';
const port = '5433';
const database = 'dbname';
const filename = 'dbname.dump';

const command = `pg_dump -U ${user} -h ${host} -p ${port} -d ${database} -F c -b -v -f "${filename}"`;

exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }

    if (stderr) {
        console.error(`Stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

This script constructs the pg_dump command with the provided parameters and then runs it using exec. The output (or any errors) of the command are logged to the console.